# I have to deleted the libNativeStrands.a file which uses UIWebView. After that I am getting the below error _OBJC_CLASS_$_IMNativeStrands",InMobi

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, linker-errors, inmobi

I have to deleted the  libNativeStrands.a file which uses UIWebView. After that I am getting the below error *OBJC_CLASS*$_IMNativeStrands",InMobi

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IMNativeStrands", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in IMNativeAdTableCell.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

IMNativeAdTableCell.m seems to be still referencing libNativeStrands.

1. check the architecture you are building for.
2. Check for the class IMNativeStrands in your code.
3. Clean up derived data directory(may be you have done it already.
   /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData//Build/

Comment: I have deleted the derived data. Excluded arch has arm64

Comment: what about IMNativeStrands.m did you check?

Comment: Yes, IMNativeStrands.m is a file which is used and available under the INMobi. It is manually added or linked in the Xcode.

Comment: Sorry, is IMNativeStrands part of the .a? 
Is IMNativeAdTableCell part of the project?

Comment: So this is what I assume is happening.
IMNativeAdTableCell is part of the project and IMNativeStrands is part of the .a library now you have removed .a library so obviously IMNativeStrands will not be built and the symbol will not be found!.

Comment: Yes, it correct. So how can I import the euivalent using the InMobi.xcframework. IMNativeStrands is InMobi/IMNativeStrands.h InMobi/IMNativeDelegate.h

Comment: After deleting the InMobi it shows the error as Classes/IMNativeAdTableCell.h:10:9: fatal error: 'IMNativeStrandsDelegate.h' file not found
#import "IMNativeStrandsDelegate.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated

Comment: ya sorry I cannot help any more looks like you need the library why are you removing it in the first place?

Comment: if you want to use .xcframework then just include it in buildphases-> link with libraries

Comment: Because the IMNativeStrands.a using the UIWebView. So I am removing it

Comment: ok if .xcframework is newer one then include .xcframework and use the appropriate classes

Comment: share your code and the InMobi xcframework link here if you need some help

Comment: https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/sdk-documentation/ios-guidelines/overview-ios-guidelines#add-inmobi%C2%A0sdk